# Is there any simple way in Python to pair neighboring elements in an array?

Tags: python, arrays

Say I've got `A = [1, 2, 3, 4]`
I want to have `B = [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]`,
so I can check if `B` contains `(u,v)`.

Already tried iterating from `0` to `len(A)-1` checking every `(A[i],A[i]+1)` but this seems to be inefficient.

```py
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in range(len(A)-1):
   if A[i] == u and A[i+1] == v:
      #assume true
#assume false
```

Having `B` as above would help in this problem and some others, I think.

Comment: zip with a and a[1:]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
B = [(i,j) for i,j in zip(A, A[1:])]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: No need to unpack then repack each tuple; `B = [t for t in zip(...)]`, which is then equivalent to `B = list(zip(...))`.

Answer (score 3):

`zip(A, A[1:])` is nice, but has the drawback of having to virtually duplicate `A` first. A pair of separate iterators can be used instead.

```
from itertools import tee

a1, a2 = tee(A)
next(a2)
B = list(zip(a1, a2))
```

You can replace the call to `next` with a call to `islice` that can be inlined.

```
from itertools import tee, slice

a1, a2 = tee(A)
B = list(zip(a1, islice(a2, 1))
```

These are both a little slower (though still linear) than zipping two concrete lists, but use O(1) instead of O(n) additional memory.

Comment: This is fast and elegant :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use list comprehention:

```
B=[(A[i],A[i+1]) for i in range(len(A)-1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will create the B the you are looking for

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
B=[]
for i in range(len(A)-1):
    B.append((A[i],A[i+1]))

print(B)
#outputs: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```